# Using FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion to convert tab files?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, tab, data-interoperability

I'm trying to use FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion() to convert tab files to shapefiles. When I run the code below, the error says

> C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\Historic_Misc_Heritage.TAB Failed
>   to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features:
>   Dataset C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\Historic_Misc_Heritage.TAB
>   does not exist or is not supported. Failed to execute
>   (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
import os

path = "C:/temp1"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path,topdown=False):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".TAB"):
         tabFile = os.path.join(root, file)
         print(tabFile)

         outLocation = "C:/temp3/results.gdb"
         outFeatureClass = "shapefiles"
         arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversio(tabFile,outLocation, outFeatureClass)
```

When I comment out the FeatureClassToFeatureClass code and print(tabFile) tabFile's contents are printed as..

```
C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\Historic_Misc_Heritage.TAB
C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\Identified_Places_Heritage.TAB
C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\places_of_history.TAB
C:/temp1\Overlays\Character_Places\places_of_culture.TAB
etc
etc
```

I'm unsure why its saying the dataset doesn't exist and why tabFile isn't the correct input parameter for FeatureClassToFeatureClass() to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FeatureClassToFeatureClass\_conversion to convert tab to shapefiles?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210291/using-featureclasstofeatureclass-conversion-to-convert-tab-to-shapefiles)

Comment: Can you please explain what the difference is between your previous question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210291/using-featureclasstofeatureclass-conversion-to-convert-tab-to-shapefiles/210300#comment320519_210300) and this one?

Comment: Here I'm trying to implement the FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion part now. Please see an error message

Comment: `inFeatures = "tabFile"` should be `inFeatures = tabFile` or just use `tabFile` instead of `inFeatures` further down.

Comment: @TonyBonomo what was the result?  Please update your question to reflect these changes

Comment: Hi, I changed it to inFeatures = tabFile. However I still get the same python error as above in my post. Does tabFile (which is a list of tab file paths) need to be in the format of a feature class or layer?

Comment: `files` is a list but in your code `tabFile` looks like it is a `*.tab` file.  Please ensure that the messages (from errors and printing) you present are coming straight from the actual code snippet that you present.

Comment: You need to know what kind of data you are outputting from your `TAB` file - you can't just export `mydata.tab`, you'd have to specify something like `mydata.tab\mydata point` to output a point shapefile from point data in your `TAB` file.

Comment: Last I heard ArcGIS doesn't support direct MapINFO TAB (MIF/TAB) conversion unless you have the interoperability extension. Have a read of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42/converting-mapinfo-tab-and-or-mif-to-shp-using-free-tools-or-arcgis-for-desktop, I'd use OGR2OGR to convert the MapINFO to Esri Shapefile and then import those. When you specify TAB files ArcGIS reads them as 'TAB delimited text files', a table format and not vector (feature) data... preview one in ArcCatalog and see what I mean.

Comment: yes Im already using the Data interoperability ext in this.

Comment: I have updated my code, python error and results.. please see update above. I'm unsure why its saying the dataset doesn't exist and why tabFile isn't the correct input parameter for FeatureClassToFeatureClass?

Comment: Perhaps try `path = r"C:\temp1"` instead of `path = "C:/temp1"`.  You also seem to have an extra level of indentation on your first `for` line and its code block

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with `TAB` files, but when I view them in ArcCatalog they appear to be similar to a geodatabase which holds different feature classes with different geometries.  When you reference a feature class in a geodatabase you construct a path like `c:\mydata\mygeodatabase.gdb\myfeatureclass` where you specify the feature class name after the geodatabase name.

It appears that you need to do something similar with the `TAB`file.  My file looked like `c:\mydata\mytabfile.tab\mytabfile point` where you've got the name and geometry type after the tab filename.

[image]

When I try to run `Feature Class to Feature Class` on just the `TAB` file I get an error (same as yours from arcpy)

[image]

But when I include the actual geometry from inside the file, the tool accepts it and outputs it as expected

[image]

You may need to modify your script to something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path,topdown=False):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".TAB"):
         fc = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
         fcnamegeom = "{} point".format(fc)
         tabFile = os.path.join(root, file, fcnamegeom)
         print(tabFile)

         outLocation = "C:/temp3/results.gdb"
         outFeatureClass = fc
         arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversio(tabFile, outLocation, outFeatureClass)
```

This takes the name of the `TAB` file and removes the extension, and uses that as the feature class name and combines geometry type `point` to it (could be changed to whatever geometry type you're using).  It then outputs the feature class to your geodatabase `results.gdb` using the feature class name as the output name.

There doesn't appear to be a way to get arcpy to automatically read the contents of the `TAB` file (using something like `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` or similar), so you may need to know what each one is beforehand - perhaps storing them in a gdb table and reading that to get the names and geometry type to pass through to your `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()` tool.